# How to git add a file only once

Tags: git

If I make changes to a file after "git add", then I have to add it again to include latest changes before commit.

Is there a way to add a file once in the beginning (so I don't lose track of it) and commit all the changes in the end?

Comment: `git add` doesn't mean you're adding the file, it means you're adding the changes.

Comment: Add `git add <file>` in the hook `pre-commit` and the file will always be added whenever you make a commit. If the file is changed, the changes are committed. If not, the command doesn't have any effect. But it might not be a good idea. When the file is changed unexpectedly, or when you do want to ignore its changes in the next commit, the changes are still committed and it may cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, as [A.H. answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066966/1256452), use `git commit -a`, but I would advise against it: As [tymtam commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066836/how-to-git-add-a-file-only-once#comment94967602_54066966), you will be setting yourself up for mistakes.  If you *do* use `git commit -a`, an earlier `git add` will suffice at commit time, as we'll see in the long description.

#### Long: Git's index, or, why you have to `git add` so often

The real problem here is—well, this depends a bit on your point of view, but Git is not going to change *its* [gitty little mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(slang)) about things—the problem is that your mental model of how Git works probably doesn't match how Git actually works.  Specifically, it does not account for the way Git keeps slapping you in the face with Git's *index*.

The index is also called the *staging area* or the *cache*, depending on who or what part of Git is doing the calling.  What, precisely, the index *is*, is often not well-described.  It's hard to do a complete job of it because it has multiple uses, but the best short description I have found is this: **The index contains the files that will go into the *next* commit.**  (This leaves out a few subtleties of the index, such as how it's used during `git merge`, but captures its major essence.)

**These files, stored in the index, are not differences.  They are complete, full copies of the entire files!**  When you run `git commit`, Git *does not use what is in your work-tree*.  Instead, Git just packages up whatever is in the index *then*, and uses that to make the new commit.

The way this works is that when you first use `git checkout` to select some commit to work on, Git takes the frozen, read-only, compressed, Git-only-format files *out* of the commit, thaws them out, de-compresses them, and writes these now-*useful* versions of each file into your work-tree.

Other version control systems do this too, but those other systems stop here: they have only the frozen, committed, VCS-form files and the thawed, useful, work-tree copies.  So these other systems, when you tell them to make a *new* commit, will, slowly, carefully, one file at a time, work through your entire work-tree, preparing each file by compressing it down and freezing it and getting it ready for the next commit.  In larger projects, this can take many seconds or even multiple minutes: you invoke the "make new commit" verb, then take a break or go to lunch, because the commit won't be done for a long time.

Git, however, does something different, and arguably smarter, but also far more frustrating.  When you first `git checkout` that original commit, Git takes the frozen copies of each file and just thaws them a little bit, as it were.  It puts these semi-frozen, Git-only copies of each file into its index.  There they sit, ready to be flash-frozen into the *next* commit.  Only once any given file is in the index can that file be de-compressed into the work-tree so that you can use it.

Later, when you run `git add`, *now* Git looks at the work-tree version.  It sometimes also uses some additional saved information in the index entry—saved stuff about the work-tree—to decide whether a file *needs* to be copied back, but in principle, what Git does is to copy the file back into the index *now*.  It's at `git add` time that Git does the slow painful re-compressing into the Git-only format.  It puts the latest copy of the file *into* the index, overwriting the previous copy.

Of course, if you change the file in the work-tree again, you have to re-copy it into the work-tree again.  That's why you have to re-`add` the file.  The add step doesn't mark the work-tree file at all.  Instead, it *copies* the work-tree file, into the index copy.

The fact that each file has a copy in the index is the key to understanding how `.gitignore` really works, too.  **It's the presence, or absence, of a file in the index that determines whether the file is *tracked*.**  Only an *untracked* file can be ignored, so if a file is in the index, listing it in `.gitignore` has no effect.  And, since `git checkout` copies all the frozen files *into* the index, if there's a commit that has some file, that file will *become* tracked at the time you `git checkout that-particular-commit`, even if it's listed in `.gitignore`.

Note that there is a flag to `git add` that tells it: *For every file that is already in the index, check to see if I've updated the work-tree copy.  If so, do a `git add` of that file.*  (That includes *removing* the file from the index if it has been removed from the work-tree.)  To do this, run `git add -u`.  But since it *starts* with what's *already in the index*, it skips over any all-new work-tree files.  These *untracked* files remain untracked.

Using `git commit -a` is essentially the same<sup>1</sup> as running `git add -u` just before running `git commit`.  So, for all files that are in the index *right then*—including any you added since you extracted the current commit—this will check to see if the index copy should be replaced by the work-tree copy.  But any *untracked* files won't be added.  Using `git commit -a` is convenient and, well, *almost* works.

---

<sup>1</sup>The "essentially" here starts to show its cracks if you mix in some of the other `git commit` options, specifically `--only` or `--include`.  These affect how Git uses the index, or—for `--only`—whether it uses the *standard* index at all during the commit.  As this implies, you can create special-purpose *temporary* index files.  I'm not going to get into those details here, but, e.g., `git stash` uses this to do its fancy tricks.

Comment: Just to be precise. The added files are not "in the index". They are mentioned in the index, but they are compressed and then stored as:
`<root-of-the-repo>/.git/objects/<first-two-characters-of-the-sha-1>/<following-38-characters-of-the-sha-1>`

Comment: @salvador: yes, the freeze-drying actually just re-uses an existing blob object (if possible) or, if necessary, creates a new blob object, to hold the contents. The index then holds the hash ID. However, the blob isn't *necessarily* in `.git/objects/xx/xxx...` as objects eventually become *packed* to save even more space. If you're re-using an existing object, the object may well be packed already.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as "add everthing automatically from now on to the index". The next best thing you can do is

```
git commit -a
```

where `-a` means (quoting the manual)

```
  -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
       modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are
       not affected.
```

You can wrap that into custom git alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.ci "commit -a"
```

Comment: Please note the that `commit -a`, as the help states, does not include, new files. I've been caught so many times it's not funny...